# echo command in php doesn't get executed

Tags: php

echo command is not getting executed.

```
echo "<script>alert('Attendence Updated')</script>";
header("location: http://localhost/classroom/adminportal.php");
```

Comment: There must be something else in that code, because there's nothing with what you've shown here that wouldn't make it print.

Comment: But the header function won't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a message to the user before redirecting, you cannot use `header( 'Location: ...' )`, because you cannot send any output before the headers are sent.

You could use following:

```
<?php
header("refresh:0; url=http://localhost/classroom/adminportal.php");
echo "<script>alert('Attendence Updated')</script>";
```